# how to style margins between items in a <dl> list?

Tags: css, twitter, widget

So im integrating this Twitter widget into xhtml.

( http://help.twitter.com/forums/10711/entries/15354 )

The code is:

```
<dl id="twitter_update_list"></dl>
```

...then a couple lines of javascript.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to get any space between the list items. All i need are a couple br tags in between each item.

Im assuming i can css style the dl somehow without conflicting with the already established twitter class?

Any ideas? Just need a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
dl#twitter_update_list li {
  // margin, padding, line-height
}
```

This will apply any rules to all list-items found within `#twitter_update_list`. I took a look at an example of this widget on http://www.dustindiaz.com/search/?q=from:evan and found only that each tweet is contained within a `div` having the class `twtr-tweet`. I'm not sure if that's the standard, or if this is just the way this particular user imlemented this tool. If the former, you wouldn't be styling `li` elements, you'd be stying:

```
.twtr-tweet {
  // margin, padding, line-height
}
```

Comment: Hey one more thing i thought i'd throw at ya... also about this twitter widget integration. Why would IE display long urls (links within the list item) as breaking the containing DIV? Meanwhile FF just continues the url onto the next line, nice and clean.

Any idea?

Comment: That's just the way both browsers handle URLs. You can ask another question about how to fix this behavior in IE if you like :)

Comment: ya just did, well thanks for the help. btw - the 1st idea def worked.

Comment: solution: word-wrap: break-word;

Answer (score 0):

display:block;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;

or

display:block;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;

if I understand the layout correctly...  set the size elements to a different size as 10 isn't probably enough.